# Unable to Unregister WinzIp Self Extractor License Key

Tags: windows-7, winzip

I have a Windows 7 machine and I have a licensed version of Winzip SelfExtratcor 4.0 in "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip Self-Extractor".I could launch the self extractor and I can see the License details.
I need to move this Self- Extractor to a Win 10 machine.
When I try to uninstall I don't see it in Control Panel \ Programs and Features.

Is there a way I can unregister the license key and move it to a different machine

When I google I only get steps for WinZip and not WinZip Self Extractor

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way I can unregister the license key and move it to a different machine

> **Before transferring WinZip**
>
> You should record or obtain your registration information. Here are
>   two ways to find the information:
>
> 1. Open the About WinZip dialog
> 2. Use the search options in What is my registration code?
>
> **Transferring your application**
>
> 1. Uninstall WinZip from the old computer
> 2. Download and install the correct WinZip version* on the other computer
> 3. Register WinZip using the information you recorded

Source [How to transfer WinZip to another computer - WinZip - Knowledgebase](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/203/)

---

#### When I try to uninstall I don't see it in Control Panel > Programs and Features.

> If you are not able to uninstall WinZip using the appropriate Control
>   Panel feature, you may be able to uninstall manually. Uninstall issues
>   can occur for a variety of reasons. It is even possible that you will
>   not find WinZip in the list of programs that can be uninstalled.
>
> You may want to refer to some of the information in Command Line
>   Basics when following these instructions.
>
> To uninstall manually:
>
> Note: Steps 1-4 only apply to versions 19 and 20.
>
> 1. On the keyboard, press Windows key (the Windows key)+R to open Run
> 2. Copy and paste the following into Run:    `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
> 3. Click OK to open the All User's Startup folder
> 4. Delete the following shortcut files if they are present: FAH, Update Notifier, WinZip Previewer
> 5. Open the WinZip folder, usually in C:\Program Files
>
>    Note: If you have a 32-bit version of WinZip on a 64-bit version of
>      Windows, you will need to open C:\Program Files (x86)
> 6. Select and delete the Utils folder
> 7. Click Continue in the Access Denied dialog, if it displays
> 8. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on the keyboard to select all of the WinZip program files
> 9. Right click anywhere in the highlighted area and choose Properties
> 10. Click the box next to Read Only until it is clear (no check mark, not colored)
> 11. Click OK
> 12. Select the radio button next to "Apply changes to the selected items, subfolders and files" in the Confirm Attribute Changes dialog
> 13. Click OK
> 14. Click Continue in the Access Denied dialog, if it displays
> 15. Right click Start and choose Command Prompt (Administrator)
>         For Windows 7 and Vista, you will need to find Command Prompt on the Start menu, right click, and choose Run as administrator
> 16. In the Command Prompt window type the appropriate line below (32-bit WinZip or 64-bit WinZip):
>
>     ```
>     "%ProgramFiles%\WinZip\winzip32" /uninstall
>     "%ProgramFiles%\WinZip\winzip64" /uninstall
>     ```
>
>     For a 32-bit WinZip on a 64-bit system, use:
>
>     ```
>     "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinZip\winzip32" /uninstall
>     ```
> 17. Press Enter on the keyboard
> 18. Respond to the dialogs that display to uninstall WinZip
> 19. Restart your computer
> 20. Delete the WinZip folder in the Program Files folder (removing all remaining files and subfolders)
>
> If WinZip was on the uninstall list when you first tried uninstalling,
>   continue with the steps below.
>
> 1. On the keyboard, press Windows key (the Windows key)+R to open Run
> 2. In the Run dialog type: regedit and click OK, which will open the Registry Editor
> 3. Click Yes in the User Account Control dialog (if necessary)
> 4. Browse to:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\> {CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240??}
>    ```
>
>    Note: The last two characters are represented by question marks. The
>      actual characters vary by WinZip version.
>
>    Each backslash represents the end of an item. Start by clicking the
>      triangle next to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, then the one next to Microsoft,
>      until you reach `{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240??}`
> 5. Click on `{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240??}` to display its contents in the right pane of the Registry Editor and make certain
>      that the DisplayName string value shows this to be WinZip
> 6. After clicking `{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C240??}` to select it, press Delete on the keyboard
> 7. Respond to the warning dialog that displays and close the Registry Editor

Source [Manually uninstalling WinZip - WinZip - Knowledgebase](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/244/)

Comment: Removing the registry key is unnecessary if you have already removed the program.  WinZip to my knowledge doesn’t use an activation system outside of a license key.  *It’s just extra work that doesn’t achieve very much.*

Comment: @Ramhound It might not be necessary, but the instructions are from WinZip ...

Comment: The given steps are for Winzip. I am looking for WinZip Self-Extractor . The registry entry given is not available for WinZip Self-Extractor

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: @subbu [How do I contact WinZip technical support about a problem? - WinZip - Knowledgebase](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/212/)